# Doing OLS, we can add new features by G-S orthogonalising. What is the fastest way to compare MSE improvement between two potential new regressors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, feature-selection, linear

[Q] Working through ESL, looking at QR decomp for OLS. Lets say we want to add a few new features: we can iteratively add them by orthogonalising. If we only want to include a subset, how could you evaluate which features improve R2/MSE the most?

In ESL (here's a link) they describe "Regression by Successive Orthogonalization" in algorithm 3.1 : basically, I can do linear regression of multiple features by orthogonalizing the column space of X using Gram-Schmidt and get each coefficient by doing 1 variable OLS of y against the residual (the orthogonal vector we just made). Now I'm thinking - if I do this for a set of features, then take another set and want to evaluate the utility of the new feature added, what is the quickest way to do this? We can calculate each new beta value by orthogonalizing each vector separately against the original dataset; for each X_j in the new dataset, we get

```
z_j = new X_j orthogonalised against X_1...X_n , j>n.   beta_j = <z_j,y>/||z||2
```

(basically extending the original QR decomposition of the first dataset by 1 feature each time) I feel like we should be able to immediately conclude something from either the beta_j or the <z_j,y> term in terms of how useful the new addition is, because: 1. z_j is orthogonal to X_1...X_n 2. <z_j,y> is the covariance of z_j and y i.e covariance of the residual information we get from X_j with y Based on that, if we want to answer "which new feature improves the model R2 the most", it feels like we need to pick the X_j that maximises <z_j,y> - is that correct? I'm a bit worried that this would mean that we just pick the X_j with biggest variance, though - i had originally thought we just wanted the maximal beta_j, but that doesn't really make sense unless we normalise our X matrix first.

Comment: If (a big if if you ask me...) you want to find out which variable most improves R^2, why not add it the "usual" way without orthogonalizing first - that seems quick enough, and surely quick to implement